# Random color on mouse-hover

Tags: javascript, css, random, colors, hover

I am using the following code to change the color. I have :root{} in my CSS.

I have a random shadow color on each reload of the page, so I almost got it right.
Is it possible to get a random color on each item with every 'hover'?

JS:

```
function getColor() {
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}

document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--shadowColor', getColor());
```

CSS for referencing

```
:root {
    --shadowColor: blue;
}

.nav a:hover {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: ;
    background-size: 1px 50px;

    text-shadow: -2px 0px var(--shadowColor);
}
```

Comment: While I understand your question: why in the world would you do that in the first place? It's a usability nightmare and even as a gimmick extremely annoying to say the least. This is surely possible. But show us your attempts, what went wrong, what you've learned from it and where you're stuck. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: @herrbischoff perhaps this isn't for practical/production use, and more rather for better understanding of how to manipulate custom variables through JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `onmouseover` event. Apply the same logic that you used for on-page load

```js
function getColor() {
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}

function setColor() {
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--shadowColor', getColor());
}
setColor();
```

```css
:root {
    --shadowColor: blue;
}

.nav a:hover {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: ;
    background-size: 1px 50px;

    text-shadow: -2px 0px var(--shadowColor);
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <a href="#" onmouseover="setColor();"> Check the color item 1 </a>
  <a href="#" onmouseover="setColor();"> Check the color item 2 </a>
  <a href="#" onmouseover="setColor();"> Check the color item 3 </a>
</div>
```

Without using `onmouseover` on HTML line

```js
function getColor() {
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}

function setColor() {
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--shadowColor', getColor());
}

setColor();

document.body.addEventListener('mouseover', function (evt) {
if (evt.target.tagName === 'A') {
    setColor();
}
}, false);
```

```css
:root {
    --shadowColor: blue;
}

.nav a:hover {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: ;
    background-size: 1px 50px;

    text-shadow: -2px 0px var(--shadowColor);
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <a href="#" > Check the color item 1 </a>
  <a href="#" > Check the color item 2 </a>
  <a href="#" > Check the color item 3 </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and changes Deepu! I really appreciate it.

Is it possible to change the effect through the JS file? or is it only possible with adding onmouseover on the html lines. (I have tried to add an eventlistener but I am stuck on the last lines.)

If it is not possible I still appreciate the effort!

Comment: @Rensrups I have added a new solution. Check the  **Show code snippet link**

Comment: Thank you, I see how this works now and I appreciate your help very much. thanks